# How to disable SSL 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: ssl

I have disabled SSL 2.0 and 3.0 on a PC in our environment as described in the articles linked below, but for some reason this PC is still being flagged by our security software for SSL 2.0 and 3.0.

https://help.duo.com/s/article/3400?language=en_US

https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/iis-disabling-ssl-v3.htm

I looked at the PC again and verified that the registry keys are still set correctly.  With SSL disabled in the registry in this way, is it even possible for anything on the computer to turn on or otherwise use SSL 2.0/3.0?  My understanding is that any applications that need it will simply stop working.

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: This depends on the OS, and applications can be bundled with their own "SSL" stack. Also "this PC is still being flagged by our security software" does not explain which "security software" and what it does and how it flags it, etc. Anyway all of this is not about programming, so offtopic here. You should have more chance on [su] I guess but you would need to provide more details in your question.

Comment: This is on Windows 10, and we're using Nessus.  I guess my question was more on the Windows side of things rather than Nessus, as I wanted to exhaust the possibilities on the PC side before reaching the conclusion that it's a false positive, or whatever else.  I didn't see a category drop-down or anything like that, did I post this in the wrong section?

Comment: The whole website is about programming questions, there are no sections. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Hence I think  [su] or [sf] may be more on topic for your case, depending on the situation (read their own help sections to find out more what is on topic or not and how to write good questions).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have posted this on Super User.